# What is the best way to share struct definition in C and Golang

Tags: go, interop

I’m trying to send some data from C program to Golang. The data is representing by raw C struct. I’m trying to unmarshal it in Golang.

A sample like this:

```
typedef struct tagA {
    int64_t a;
    int64_t b;
    char  c[1024];
}A;
```

A method is to rewrite this C struct to Golang struct. Say:

```
type A struct{
    a int64
    b int64
    c [1024]byte
}
```

And then convert raw data byte stream to it using `encoding/binary` .  But using this method, I should maintain two different-interrelated structs.

Another method is to use `Cgo`, just import the C language head file(`.h`) contains this struct, and use `C.A` and unsafe point to convert raw data to struct C.A. But it’s somehow buggy, and I’m crashed to convert C char array to Golang string.

What’s your option? Any suggestion?

Comment: That's a very bad approach. Define a serial data format and use proper serialisation with bitshifts/masking on both sides. There are enough Q&A about this to be found by a simple search.

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, when changing encapsulation fields, both side code shell be changed? Is there an approach to “share” definition in one place?

Comment: @LiLinZhe, you can use a serializtion protocol with a schema, like "Protocol Buffers" or FlatBuffers

Comment: As @JimB suggested, I'd use [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) or [flatbuffer](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) for this if you want an external schema, but `cgo` is likely easier/better if the project is suited to FFI.

For `cgo`, you'll have to use a C header file as you mentioned, as well as the `C.GoString` and `C.CString` functions, which are mentioned in [this article](https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo#TOC_2.). The [`cgo` command reference](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo) is also informative.

Answer (score 9):

one way using cgo: you may access any fields of C struct, using `var s *C.struct_tagA = &C.N` or simply using `s := &C.N` like this working sample code:

```
package main

/*
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef struct tagA {
    int64_t a;
    int64_t b;
    char  c[1024];
}A;

A N={12,22,"test"};
*/
import "C"

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    a int64
    b int64
    c [1024]byte
}

func main() {
    s := &C.N // var s *C.struct_tagA = &C.N

    t := A{a: int64(s.a), b: int64(s.b)}
    length := 0
    for i, v := range s.c {
        t.c[i] = byte(v)
        if v == 0 {
            length = i
            break
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("len(s.c):", len(s.c)) // 1024
    str := string(t.c[0:length])       
    fmt.Printf("len:%d %q \n", len(str), str) // len:4 "test" 

    s.a *= 10
    fmt.Println(s.a) // 120

}
```

output:

```
len(s.c): 1024
len:4 "test" 
120
```

you may use `s.a` , `s.b` and `s.c` directly in Golang. you do not need to copy all of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare variable of struct type in Golang reference to struct C by `C.struct_YourStruct`

Comment: An example would be nice.